# Unable to create Database in Rails using rake db:create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a new rails project and did few configuration changes in `database.yml`.
Then had to create the database using the command `rake db:create` inorder to continue developing the application but I get the error below.

```
Els-MacBook-Pro:eshop el$ rake db:create
warning ../../package.json: No license field                                                                 
FATAL:  role "eshop" does not exist
Couldn't create 'eshop_development' database. Please check your configuration.
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  role "eshop" does not exist

Tasks: TOP => db:create
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
Els-MacBook-Pro:eshop el$
```

I will also post the contents of my `database.yml` below:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  host: localhost
  database: eshop_development
  username: eshop
  password: eshop

test:
  <<: *default
  host: localhost
  database: eshop_test
  username: eshop
  password: eshop

production:
  <<: *default
  database: eshop_production
  username: eshop
  password: <%= ENV['ESHOP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

[image]

I will be grateful if someone can help me figure out why I cannot create a db. I have read all types of solutions and none seems to be working. Thanks.

Comment: did you already create role eshop on your postgresql?

Comment: Yes I think so. If not how do I create that. Because when I created the new rails app few days back, the error I was getting was `unable to connect to server` I came back to continue work and I now get this error of `eshop does not exist`

Comment: maybe this https://kb.objectrocket.com/postgresql/how-to-create-a-role-in-postgres-1454

Comment: you should check the role if it exist

Comment: @dedypuji Thanks. I created the role and was able to create the DB

Answer (score 3):

In your database.yaml you need to add a port: 5432, and then Try rails db:create, as rake has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

create a role in your postrgesql database named 'eshop'